# Replace numpy ndarry negative elements with 0 (zero)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

suppose I have a numpy ndarray

```
[[2, -7, 5], [-6, 2, 0] [1, -4, 2], [-2, 6, 8]]
```

How to get a numpy nd arry with all negative elements replaced by 0:

```
[[2, 0, 5], [0, 2, 0] [1, 0, 2], [0, 6, 8]]
```

Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) for this, clipping between zero and infinity:

```
arr = np.array([[2, -7, 5], [-6, 2, 0], [1, -4, 2], [-2, 6, 8]])

np.clip(arr, a_min = 0, a_max = np.inf)

array([[2., 0., 5.],
       [0., 2., 0.],
       [1., 0., 2.],
       [0., 6., 8.]])
```

Otherwise, you can use something like this (note this changes the array in place):

```
arr[arr <= 0] = 0

>>> arr
array([[2, 0, 5],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [0, 6, 8]])
```

Comment: note the np.clip out argument - from docs:
outndarray, optional
The results will be placed in this array. It may be the input array for in-place clipping. out must be of the right shape to hold the output. Its type is preserved.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `np.where()` too:

```
arr = np.array([[2, -7, 5], [-6, 2, 0], [1, -4, 2], [-2, 6, 8]])
result = np.where(arr<0, 0, arr)
```

Output:

```
[[2 0 5]

 [0 2 0]
 [1 0 2]
 [0 6 8]]
```